# what is probability density function (PDF) of periodic signal

Tags: audio, fourier-transform, algorithms, statistics, speech

Anybody knows what is the best pdf for periodic signal ?

I have signal with $480$ samples $\left(16000*0.03=480\right)$ but I could not find the exact pdf for that. sometimes it appear like 2 mixed Gaussian.

Comment: What is the source of randomness; the amplitude, the phase, or offset?

Comment: Amplitude vs time

Comment: Related: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/184/29

Answer (score 3):

There is no best pdf for a periodic signal. There is also no way to find the 'exact' pdf of a measured signal. What you have to do is to measure the pdf from the data. Use a histogram to approximate the pdf of your data. Define a number of intervals within the amplitude range of your signal and simply count the numbers of data samples per interval. This gives you the histogram which is an approximation of the pdf of your signal.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. I did so but every times the shape of histogram is changed. It means, it is not like noise that has Gaussian distribution ?